# UK Visa (Student Visa)

Tags: visas, uk, passport-renewals

I’m from India, I’ve got an offer to study in the UK and I’m applying for the Tier 4 Visa but my passport is expiring in 5 months. Will I still be able to get a visa for four years? Or should I renew my passport before applying my visa ?

Comment: Obviously renew your passport before applying, no rocket science